# How to draw a basic histogram with X and Y axis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I want to make a simple histogram which involves two vectors ,

```
values <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
freq <- c(4,6,4,4,3,2,1,1)
df <- data.frame(values,freq)
```

Now the `data.farame` `df` consists the following values :

```
values freq
 1    4
 2    6
 3    4
 4    4
 5    3
 6    2
 7    1
 8    1
```

Now I want to draw a simple histogram, in which `value`s are on the x axis and `freq` is on y axis. I am trying to use the `hist` function, but I am not able to give two variables. How can I make a simple histogram from this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = values, y = freq)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the frequencies already, what you really want is a bar plot:

```
barplot(df$freq,names.arg=df$values)
```

If you've got your heart set on using `hist`, you should do:

```
hist(rep(df$values,df$freq))
```

Please read `?barplot` and `?hist` for further plotting options.

---

Also, because I'm somewhat of a zealot, I think the code looks cleaner if you use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) #convert df to a data.table by reference
df[,barplot(freq,names.arg=values)]
```

and

```
df[,hist(rep(values,freq))]
```