# Creating an image histogram from a csv

Tags: r, plot

So I have a csv file like this:

```
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
...
250,1
251,0
252,0
253,2
254,2
255,9
```

It represents the histogram of a greyscale image. The file indicates that color `255` occurs 9 times, color `250` occurs 1 time, etc.

I read the file in:

```
df <- read.csv("/tmp/hist.csv", header= F, dec=",")
```

And then tried to plot it:

```
hist(df$V2)
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

But what I rather would like to have is to be the colors from 0-255 on the x-axis and the frequency represented by the y-axis. How can I tell R to … turn the axis "around"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a basic histogram with X and Y axis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639990/how-to-draw-a-basic-histogram-with-x-and-y-axis-in-r)

Comment: Please see my answer below. You're using `hist` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `hist(df$V2)` creates a histogram (count table) of the occurrences of occurrences. So what you're plotting is the same as `table(df$V2)` (you should confirm this to understand what's going on). I assume this is not what you want.

Instead, I assume you want to plot the distribution of colour occurrences across all 256 colours.

You can do this in base R using `barplot`:

```
# Barplot base R
barplot(df[, 2], names.arg = df[, 1]);
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot2`:

```
# (gg)plot
colnames(df) <- c("colour", "count");
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(colour), y = count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity");
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
# Your sample data
df <- read.csv(text =
    "0,0
     1,0
     2,0
     3,0
     4,0
     250,1
     251,0
     252,0
     253,2
     254,2
     255,9", header = T)
```